# Allocating aligned data (memalign) in Visual C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, alignment

I have a small prototype program written in C++ running under Linux using the `memalign` function to allocate regions aligned to boundaries like pages. Is there an equivalent function in Visual C++?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6(v=VS.100).aspx). Note that memory must be deallocated using `_aligned_free`, and that alignment is restricted to powers of 2.

If you need more flexibility, it's not too hard to handroll your own solution which `malloc`s `alignment + bytes` memory chunks to start with.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on creating a custom aligned malloc?